# Image Placing order...image comes as one side

Tags: php

Here is my script..thing is that..am getting image under that name , description and price are coming...but how can i display image one side **beside** that all these(name,price,desc) follow sequence..

ref link:  http://www.qualitycodes.com/tutorials/demos/php/shopping/products.php

```
<body>
<div id=cart align="center">
<table border="0" cellpadding="2px" width="600px">
<h1 align="center">Products</h1>
    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT serial, name, description, price,picture FROM products;";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
        while(list($id, $name, $description, $price,$picture) = mysql_fetch_row($result)) { 
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td align=left>";
            echo "<input type='button' onClick=\"window.open('cart.php?action=add&id=" . $id . "','_self');\" value='Add to Cart' />";
            echo "<hr color=grey size=\"0\" >";         
            echo "</td>";   
            echo "</tr>";           
        }   
    ?>  
</table>
<a href="cart.php">View Cart</a>
<input type="image" src="submit.gif" alt="Submit" width="48" height="48" />
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use stylesheets

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#mainContent
{
width:600px;
}
#leftContent
{
display:inline;
float:left;
}
#rightContent
{
display:inline;
float:left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainContent">
    <div id="leftContent">
        <img src="filename.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div id="rightContent">
         <?php
           //Database code and values 
         ?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```